# Saving One-To-Many Model With Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.

Say I have two models, Team and Player. They look like this:

team.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: teams
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :players

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end
```

player.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: players
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  team_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team
end
```

Super simple. And I can do the following without any troubles:

```
> params = { team: {
>       name: "Foo", players_attributes: [
>         {name: "Bar"}
>       ]
>     }}
> team = Team.new(params[:team]) # => #<Team id: nil, name: "Foo", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
> team.save # => true
> team.players.first.name # => "Bar"
```

Okay. Now let's say I update the Player model so that one cannot create a Player without it belonging to a Team:

player.rb:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: players
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  team_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :team

    validates_presence_of :team
end
```

Now when I try the same thing:

```
> params = { team: {
>       name: "Foo", players_attributes: [
>         {name: "Bar"}
>       ]
>     }}
> team = Team.new(params[:team]) # => #<Team id: nil, name: "Foo", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
> team.save # => false
> team.errors # => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000002bd13f0 @base=#<Team id: nil, name: "Foo", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={:"players.team"=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

Without the team being required by the player, the team_id is obviously being set with the nested attributes. However, as soon as I require it the validation busts before it has a chance to be set. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  validates_presence_of :team
end
```

With

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players, inverse_of: :team
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team, inverse_of: :players
  validates_presence_of :team
end
```

Add `inverse_of` option in the associations.

Comment: Huh! I've never used that before, and it solves the issue. Thanks @Kirti!